# How to listen for changes to window.location.search in 2019

Tags: javascript, html, query-string, pushstate, popstate

I would like to update `window.location.search` *without reloading the document* and then execute a function based on the updated values in `window.location.search`.

When the user clicks a button, that button's `onclick` event fires the following function:

```
window.history.pushState({action : 'myAction'}, document.title, '?action=myAction');
```

So far so good. The `window.location.search` updates in the browser URL bar.

But I can't find a general background event listener which detects this update - something like `onhashchange` but for query strings.

The best I can come up with is:

```
window.history.pushState({action : 'myAction'}, document.title, '?action=myAction');
window.history.pushState({action : 'myAction'}, document.title, '?action=myAction');
window.history.back();

window.addEventListener('popstate', () => console.log(event.state.action));
```

This works but I'm convinced there must be a more elegant approach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Final Answer:

I was mostly happy with the **Second Attempt** answer immediately below.

But I really didn't like:

```
history.back();
history.forward();
```

which I adopted to trigger the `popstate` event, manually.

In practice, I found this hack worked sometimes, it was slow at other times and on occasion it failed completely.

On paper, it feels too makeshift.

After repeatedly searching and experimenting (this was remarkably hard to find), I have finally found the correct syntax for manually firing a `popstate` event.

It's as ***simple*** as `dispatching` this:

```
new Event('popstate')
```

Like this:

```
let myEvent = new Event('popstate');
window.dispatchEvent(myEvent);
```

So the final code is:

```
window.history.pushState({action : 'myAction'}, document.title, '?action=myAction');
let queryStringChange = new Event('popstate');
window.dispatchEvent(queryStringChange);
```

---

## Best Answer I can come up with (Second Attempt):

Building on the following:

I know for certain that the query-string will *only need to be checked* either:

1. when the page loads or reloads;
2. when `window.history.pushstate` is invoked;
3. or when (as *@Kaiido* astutely pointed out in the comments below) a page is accessed via the forward and back buttons

I also know that:

- The `window.load` event listener covers Point 1.;
- The `window.popstate` event listener covers Point 3.;

This only leaves Point 2.

---

**Dealing with Point 2**

As **MDN** reports:

> Note that just calling `history.pushState()` or `history.replaceState()`
> ***won't trigger a popstate event***. The popstate event ***will be triggered***
> by doing a browser action such as a click on the back or forward
> button (or calling `history.back()` or `history.forward()` in JavaScript).
>
> **Source:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/popstate_event

But this means that rather than using (as in my first attempt, below):

```
window.history.pushState({action : 'myAction'}, document.title, '?action=myAction');

checkQueryString(); // DIRECT INVOCATION OF FUNCTION
```

I can use instead:

```
window.history.pushState({action : 'myAction'}, document.title, '?action=myAction');
history.back();
history.forward();
```

This means that rather than needing to invoke the function directly, I can now allow the same `window.popstate` event listener covering **Point 3** to do its work, giving me cleaner, more logically separated code.

---

**N.B.** I find it... weird... that pressing the forward button alone *will* fire the `window.popstate` event listener, but invoking `window.history.pushState()` will not... (necessitating the immediately subsequent addition of `history.back(); history.forward();` to duplicate the functionality of a forward button).

But, as above, this is the best, cleanest, most optimised (in terms of logical separation and future code maintenance) solution I can come up with. If anyone has a dramatically better idea, I'll be happy to transfer the green tick.

---

## First Attempt at an Answer:

I am tentatively concluding that there is no way to achieve this effect using a background event listener which can detect when the query string updates.

Instead, since I **know** for certain that the query-string will *only need to be checked* either:

- when the page loads or reloads
- when `window.history.pushstate` is invoked

I can use the following:

```
window.addEventListener('load', checkQueryString);
```

and

```
window.history.pushState({action : 'myAction'}, document.title, '?action=myAction');

checkQueryString();
```

Comment: You would also need to listen for [`popstate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/popstate_event) event in order to catch when your user will navigate through the browser's back-next buttons.

Comment: Yes, excellent point. Thanks for catching that. So two Event Listeners then - one for `load` and one for `popstate`. If you want to post that as an alternative answer,  I'm happy to mark your improved solution as the accepted answer.

Comment: Is there any diffrence between using ``window.dispatch(myEvent)`` and using``history.back（）``? Will  using  ``window.dispatch（myEvent）`` change the ``history`` object?

Comment: Yes, there is a difference. `history.back()` (and `history.forward()`) will manipulate both the `history` object and change the `url` in the address bar. For me these were undesired side-effects. All I wanted to happen was for the `onpopstate` event to fire on `window` after I used the `pushstate` method on `window.history`.